# Loop For to export polygons from a Feature Class

Tags: arcpy, loop

I need to export 150 polygons from a feature Class. I have a python snippet code to export the polygons one by one.
I think a for loop code can do it fast, but I don't know how to write the code into the loop. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(in_features="D:/ASSUKKARGIS3/ty_plg_gglimgs_georef/plg_clip_imgs.shp", out_path="D:/ASSUKKARGIS3/plg_clips", out_name="001_clip_plg.shp", where_clause='"plg" = 1', field_mapping='plg "plg" true true false 19 Double 0 0 ,First,#,D:\ASSUKKARGIS3\ty_plg_gglimgs_georef\plg_clip_imgs.shp,plg,-1,-1', config_keyword="")
```

Answer (score 1):

Why bother writing any code?  Simply use the [Split By Attributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split-by-attributes.htm) tool. This came in as of version 10.5

Comment: Hornbydd. I tested Split By Attributes and the final product is another table. Meanwhile, I wrote the snippet code 150 times changing the field value and the name of the output feature class. This long code was time-consuming but, I have all polygons shps that I need. Thanks

Comment: You must have done something wrong, you need only supply the input dataset, the field to split on (e.g. FID) and an output workspace; to only get one table would suggest you may have had a selection on your dataset or you selected a field with no variation in value?

Comment: Hornbydd. Yes I was wrong. n my first test I exported the shp file to a .dbf table.

Comment: Hornbydd. Yes, I was wrong. In my first test, I exported the shp file to a .dbf table and then use the Split By Attributes tool. The second test I use the shp file and the result is what you say. Thank you very much indeed.